# Google Spreadsheet LOOKUP by Dynamic Value

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to use LOOKUP function that is based on a dyanmic value.  For example:

`=LOOKUP("A", C$2:C$1000, B$2:B$1000)`

The above will look for Letter A in C Column and then write the value from the corresponding B Column row.  What I wish to do is now read the Letter A from the D column, like so:

`=LOOKUP(D2, Sheet2!C$2:C$1000, Sheet2!B$2:B$1000)`

However, the above gives me an error.  Is there a way to accomplish the above?

The above keeps returning me with an error saying value not found, I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

EDIT

Ok so I have been playing more with this and I started having some very strange results.  Lets take the following table:   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ki3pmCOQoI1DLcbjEO-uwgwZGFfnHhM-fodspw8v1Qs/#gid=1001637055

Then my second sheet is this:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ki3pmCOQoI1DLcbjEO-uwgwZGFfnHhM-fodspw8v1Qs/edit#gid=1993578337

If you look at the second sheet, bob shows up multiple times and I don't understand why.

Comment: What's the error you're getting and can you provide an example with the data?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach I have updated my question, could you please have a look?

Comment: Yes, the first parameter of lookup can be a reference. The [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256570?hl=en) says as much: "search_key - The value to search for in the row or column. For example, 42, "Cats", or I24."  Also, this isn't a programming question, so I'd suggest asking at [webapps.se]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Reason for #N/A's

`lookup` produces `#N/A` if it is looking up an empty range as is the case here. `'Draft Options'!A:A is empty so lookup cannot find a value to look up against.

### Reason for multiple appearances

The documentation states that:

> The LOOKUP function will only work properly if data in search_range or
>   search_result_array is sorted. Use VLOOKUP, HLOOKUP, or other related
>   functions if data is not sorted.
>
> If search_key is not found, the item used in the lookup will be the
>   value that’s immediately smaller in the range provided. For example,
>   if the data set contains the numbers 1, 3, 5 and search_key is 2, then
>   1 will be used for the lookup.

Now, you are looking up Text but the same thing applies, it needs to be ordered alphabetically.
This is because `lookup` is doing something called [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)
Since your data is unordered and (assuming you have column A filled with keys the following can happen which leads to weird results:

1. Lookup looks at the middle entry and checks if the value comes before or
   after the lookup value in an alphabetically sorted list.
2. If it comes
   before it checks the the entry int he middle between the beginning
   of the list and the middle.
3. If your entry happens to be in the latter half lookup never finds this entry

or

3. This value might not exists so it picks the first value it can find that would come before that (assuming the data is sorted) or something (seemingly random)  where lookup finds value n to be alphabetically after the lookup value and n+1 alphabetically before and returns value n+1.

You should only use lookup if you *know* the lookup values will be there and that they will be sorted. Otherwise you might want to take a look at `VLookup` or `Index Match`

### Solution

If Column A in Sheet Draft options Actually contains those letters you are looking up you can use a simple VLookup:

```
=VLOOKUP(F2, `Draft Options`!$A$2:$B$1000, 2, FALSE)
```

Here `FALSE` specifies that VLookup shall **not** use a binary search algorithm and instead go through the list linearly (i.e. one by one) which is slower but will retrieve the first matching value or throw an error if it is not there instead of returning something odd.

Comment: Thank you for that Robin!  Would you be able to give me an example of how I would be able to accomplish my lookup problem?

Comment: That is perfect, I tested it and it works.  I got one more question for you, however I have marked your answer as correct as you have just sped up my tournament drafting by probably 50%!  So thank you for that!  However, back to that question, how would I prevent it from saying Error, would I be able to do accomplish this somehow with an if statement?

Comment: You can wrap the formula into an `IFERROR` statement like this `=IFERROR(<yourformula>, "No Player found under this ID")`

Comment: I did with IF and ISERROR combination, `=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(F2, "1"), 'Draft Options'!$A$2:$B$1000, 2, FALSE)), "", VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(F2, "1"), 'Draft Options'!$A$2:$B$1000, 2, FALSE))`